# Parse Server - S3 File adapter - accessing previous, non-s3 files

Tags: amazon-s3, digital-ocean, parse-server

We have a mobile app that runs on Parse Server 2.8.4, hosted at `DigitalOcean`. We were using the default file adapter (GridStoreAdapter) and now we want to use Spaces by DigitalOcean. This is our updated index file:

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var ParseDashboard = require('parse-dashboard');
var path = require('path');
var S3Adapter = require('parse-server').S3Adapter;
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGODB_URI;

//Set Digital Ocean Spaces EndPoint
const spacesEndpoint = new AWS.Endpoint('fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com');
//Define S3 options
var s3Options = {
  bucket: 'bucketName',
  baseUrl: 'https://example.com',
  region: 'fra1',
  directAccess: true,
  globalCacheControl: "public, max-age=31536000",
  s3overrides: {
    accessKeyId: 'accessKey',
    secretAccessKey: ' secretAccessKey',
    endpoint: spacesEndpoint
  }
};

var s3Adapter = new S3Adapter(s3Options);

var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri,
  appId: process.env.APP_ID,
  allowClientClassCreation: false,
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY,
  fileKey: 'fileKey',  
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL,
  publicServerURL: 'http://ip/parse',
  filesAdapter: s3Adapter
});
```

Everything works great! The files are stored and retrieved properly, except of the old ones! Every image that was stored with the GridStoreAdapter cannot be fetched anymore! Is there anything that can be done in order to be able to view both old and new files?

Comment: You will have to migrate your old files to Digital Ocean. [This](https://community.parseplatform.org/t/fs-chunks-in-mongodb-eating-too-much-space/568/5) thread can be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I asked you a question there! Please check it whenever you find the time!